# How to Proxy auth on PhantomJS (proxy script)

Tags: proxy, phantomjs

I go throught the intranet/internet using proxy auth.

I'm not familiar with automation throught a proxy or proxys, in IExplorer we set up the proxy on LAN settings in "Use automatic configuration script" with something like:

```
http://some-url/url/file.proxy
```

Uncheck "Automatically detect settings" and  we don't set any in the "Proxy Server" section.

So we can go "out" (internet/intranet).I have a username/password so everytime I just open a new IE instance, I got a prompt for them. How should I set this values on PhantomJS to get access to the network/internet ? I jus can't make it work, everytime I try to get a screenshot from anypage I got a webpage screenshot related to the proxy auth.

I've tried set the full/script.proxy url in the proxy prop and username/password but didn't work. Hope someone can provide an example for my understanding. Also I'll appreaciate some resources/good-to-read articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

I take a look to the script I just mentioned in my question, and just got the proxy (ip:port) needed in phantomJS.

Basically the script do some decisions about what proxy to use based on the requested url and return the proxy ip.

So the PhantomJS docs it's preety straightforward, I wasn't understanding how my proxy was set (by script),if it's your case, you can copy/paste the script url into your browser so you can analyze it and retrieve the information you need to setup phantomJs

he code in the proxy script is kind of easy to read (if you have any programming experiencie).

Comment: Where can I find your script?

Comment: Hi, sorry is an internal script (the proxy script), no way to share it, the phantomjs script is the one in the samples/documentation for phantomjs.